# Balls and Boxes Generalization

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Recently, I saw a problem here on MSE:
$$$$"Put 9 pigs in 4 pens such that there are an odd number of pigs in each pen."

Individual cases or solutions to the problem are quite easy. But how would we solve the following problem:$$$$
"Find the $number$ of ways in which the pigs can be kept in 4 pens such that there are an odd number of pigs in each pen is met."
$$$$
Taking a generalization, would there be any general formula through which we could find the number of ways in which $m$ objects are kept in $n$ boxes such that there are an odd number of objects in each box?$$$$

Any light shed on these questions (particularly the last question) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Please note that permutations are not to be considered in the final arrangement of the items.

Comment: Do you know how many answers are there for $x_1+x_2+\cdots x_k =N$ (before considering the case $x_i$'s should be odd)

Comment: I'm afraid not, Sir.

Comment: So I will explain the general case in the solution before solving this specific example.

Comment: Alright Sir, thanks a ton for your elp! I'm eagerly awaiting your solutions:)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the pig question is essentially a trick question, where we can have multiple pens enclosed in each other. I am not sure how to solve this case.

However, if you want to solve the case where pens are exclusive, i.e., solve the question "How many answers are there to $x_1 + x_2 + \dots x_n = m$, where all $x_i$ are odd?

The easiest way to explain is with an example. Say we want to see how many ways to put 14 pigs in 4 pens such that there is an odd number in each.

Then, we have $a + b + c + d = 14$, where $a, b, c, d$ are odd. However, we can define $A, B, C, D$, such that $a = 2A - 1$, $b = 2B - 1$, etc. This way, we are forcing the numbers to be odd for any natural numbers $A, B, C, D$.

Now, we have $2A - 1 + 2B - 1 + 2C - 1 + 2D - 1 = 14$, or $A + B + C + D =  9$. Finally, you can solve this with the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Agreed Sir, but the problem becomes difficult only because the pens are not necessarily exclusive.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to start somewhere, in case people don't know how to solve this case. Very interested in seeing a solution to the general problem, though!